# Error drawable and color don't change in textInputLayout

Tags: android, layout, icons, android-textinputlayout

So I'm using a textInputLayout and all I need to do is set a custom drawable for the error icon. Here's my layout and dependency

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-beta01'
```

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/text_field_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:hint="@string/insert_name_hint"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/text_field_corner"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/text_field_corner"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/text_field_corner"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/text_field_corner"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:errorTextColor="?colorAccent"
        app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_alert_black_24dp"
        app:errorIconTint="?colorAccent"
        app:errorContentDescription="@string/insert_name_hint"
        app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@color/gray"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_cool_black_24dp"
        app:startIconTint="@color/gray"
        app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
        app:hintTextColor="?colorAccent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/nameEvent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Basically, the drawable and the tints don't work, the default icon and color are used. The rest works as it should. I'm not setting anything programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem was kinda basic, but i found out after a while.
It's not a layout-level problem, but an error management problem. The error must be set on the **Input Layout** and not on the **Input EditText**. So here's the difference (i also had to add an id to the Input Layout of course):

Before

```
customView.nameEvent.error = getString(R.string.invalid_value_name)
```

After

```
customView.nameEventLayout.error = getString(R.string.invalid_value_name)
```

Yep, is **that** simple. But i think this could be a common error, so i hope this answer can help somebody out there.

Comment: Had the same issue. Thanks for adding your solution!